# _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Source' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart

I used audioplayer package file to play audio create a xylophone but play function is causing error.

I tried to cast it to Source but it is throwing  error

```
"message": "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Source'.",
```

I've been trying to run this code for a long time but it is not fetching source audio files

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(XylophoneApp());

class XylophoneApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) async {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    await player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
  }

  Expanded buildKey({Color? color, int? soundNumber}) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: color,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          playSound(soundNumber!);
        },
        child: const Text(''), // You can add text here if needed
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              buildKey(color: Colors.red, soundNumber: 1),
              buildKey(color: Colors.orange, soundNumber: 2),
              buildKey(color: Colors.yellow, soundNumber: 3),
              buildKey(color: Colors.green, soundNumber: 4),
              buildKey(color: Colors.teal, soundNumber: 5),
              buildKey(color: Colors.blue, soundNumber: 6),
              buildKey(color: Colors.purple, soundNumber: 7),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the pubscpec file code where you provided sound assets. Also, include a screenshot of the sound asset folder. As you mentioned you typecast the string so you should also mention that in another code block.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, you must pass an argument of type Source.
For example:

```
await player.play(AssetSource('note$soundNumber.wav'));
```